# How to avoid serialization of postgres json result in Sequel

Tags: json, ruby, postgresql, serialization, sequel

In a web server, I'm running a query in Postgres that performs a `select json_build_object` of an aggregation(`json_agg`). I'm using Sequel to fetch this data, and I'm getting as a value an instance of `Sequel::Postgres::JSONHash`. Then, I perform a `to_json` in order to send it to the web client.

The output of this query is very big and I think that it could be more performant If I could grab the raw json response of postgres directly and send it to the client, instead of parsing it into `JSONHash` (which is done by Sequel) and then converting it again to json.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the json_build_object from json to text in the query: `SELECT json_build_object(...)::text ...`

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy. Nice idea.